# How do I create styles for IE7 (and below)?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to implement cross browser css?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/971/what-are-the-best-ways-to-implement-cross-browser-css)

I have a site that looks more or less the same in all browsers except Internet Explorer (version 7 and below).  How do I create styles that only IE7 and below will recognize?

Comment: Agreed. Let's close this.

Answer (score 5):

What you want are [IE Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie7-or-less.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```