# Is there a general rule of thumb for which browsers to optimize your site for?

Tags: html, css, browsers, internet-explorer-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [At what visitor share do you stop supporting a given browser?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6391/at-what-visitor-share-do-you-stop-supporting-a-given-browser)

I have a site (recently relaunched it with a new design) that I have put off optimizing for ie7 for far too long. I was just never too worried about it. The site is optimized for ie8-10, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, etc.. Then I asked myself, is it even worth it?

I checked traffic over the last couple months before the relaunch and about 1.3% of the traffic is coming from ie7. So, is there a general cuttoff percentage when you would not optimize for a specific browser?

Comment: yes, these are pretty close and that gave me some valuable info. Thanks Anagio. According to the answer in this question, ie7 would fall into the "not supported" category (as under 2%).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice of you to ask this. I generally do not bother optimizing for a browser whose share on my site is not more than 5% (yes, even I got IE7 in that segment).

You could also have a small IE7 specific notification in the footer which says that the site experience is optimized for IE8 and above?

Comment: Hey thanks for the input. I think I will put a banner at the bottom saying it is optimized for ie8. I suppose I could consider myself lucky that so few people using my site use ie6 and 7. 1.3% does seem pretty insignificant and I'm a little relieved I don't really need to. The site I am working on now has been the most difficult to optimize for different browsers in general.

Comment: The answer in the link from the comment above gives a pretty good rule,

Comment: For browser that are considered "current" (most recent release of a browser that is still actively supported), we try to ensure that our sites always work. We do not, however, test in browsers that have less than 10% of our traffic (in practice this means testing in latest versions of IE, Firefox and Chrome, we've recently also started testing in Safari on MacOS and iPad).

For older versions, once the total share goes under 10% we stop caring if everything looks perfect, but we still want it to work. (Fortunately, IE6 no longer falls in this category)

Comment: Under 5% and we want it to work but only if it doesn't entail significant additional work for us (else recommend upgrading). Layout issues are entirely ignored if they do not impede functionality.

Under 2% and we consider it as being "not supported" and recommend people upgrade if there are complaints.

Comment: IE? Seriously? Anyone who uses IE should be stoned. IE is the worst of the worst.