# Should we still support IE6

Tags: web-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I bother supporting IE6?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/134/should-i-bother-supporting-ie6)

As an independent web developer, should I still be supporting IE6 on my own site/or client web sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) it depends on your audience, are they using IE6?

b) is it hard for you to support it? is your website is complicated and needs to be using technologies as css3 html5?

the underline answer after all is: don't support it if your target audience is a developed country, the statistics show no major use of IE6 anymore.

Comment: Except in China, massive usage of IE6 there.

Comment: yes as compare to rest of the world. but still in a major drop

http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-CN-monthly-201105-201205